# Why does python still work after being removed?

Tags: debian, apt, python

On Debian 8 jessie I've removed python:

```
perry@perry:~$ sudo apt-get remove python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python2.7' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
```

But somehow I can still launch python from the terminal.

```
perry@perry:~$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr 29 2015, 18:34:06) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I haven't installed it from source or from any other place but apt. How is this possible and how can I remove python completely?

Comment: what does `which python` say?

Comment: `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: As Thomas says, you've not actually removed Python - and in all honesty, you really don't want to. Doing so will render your system unusable and in need of a reinstall.

Comment: @John: What debian internals are at all dependent on python? I'm not running Ubuntu...

Comment: Whats the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep "python2.7"` ?

Comment: No core package in Debian depends on Python; if `apt` lets you remove the package without going through hoops then it's safe to do so.

Comment: "On Debian 8 jessie I've removed python:" No, you haven't: `Package 'python2.7' is not installed, so not removed` Nothing changed.

Comment: @glglgl That line is to demonstrate that python was previously removed, as claimed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It turned out that the additional package python-minimal had python installed. One does then not only have to do:

```
sudo apt-get remove python
```

but also:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-minimal
```

Comment: As `python` is dependent on `python-minimal`, you could have removed `python-minimal` directly. You can also remove multiple packages at once, by specifying multiple package names on the command line.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, I have no Debian at hand to test, but anyway:

I think you did not really uninstall `python`.
`Package 'python2.7' is not installed, so not removed` only means that a package `python2.7` is not installed. But perhaps the name is different.

`which python` says `/usr/bin/python`. That is a clear sign that you have python installed. [Here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python) is the official package.

`dpkg-query -l 'python*'` should help in getting the name/version of the installed package.

[apt-rdepends](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt-rdepends&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=Debian%208%20jessie) should tell you which packages rely on `python`.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably look at the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep python` to see all the installed python packages.  There are a few packages for various different releases that may be installed on a system.  Keep in mind that python is in the standard selections, so fully removing it will also remove other 'standard' packages like `reportbug`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> sudo apt-get purge python-minimal

The above command show remove python entirely from your system.